# Chrome extension Page Action JS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm trying to create an extension using this docs:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

I want a part of JS code to run when document is ready (loaded).

This is my **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "OwnExtension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://my.site.eu/*"],
        "css": ["styles.css"],
        "js": ["main.js"]
    }
    ]
}
```

This is my **main.js**:

```
alert(10);
```

Am I doing sth wrong, that nothing happend when page https://my.site.eu/ loaded in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alert() doesn't work from a content script.

Try console.log("hello") and you should see it in the developer panel when you view your extension in debug mode.